# PEO-mission mapping of an program

Tags: javascript, php

Here I have to do mapping of missions of an program to the PEOs( program educational objectives) of that program...So I have made a table and divided it into rows and columns..Now I give the weightage values as 1(low), 2(medium),3(high) and blank as drop down...If missions are correlated with the PEO's then they will select any of the value from the drop down and if not correlate then will select the blank...So my question is after selecting the values from drop down I have to calculate the average of each of the PEOs. How can I calculate the average from the table  ignoring the null values and how can I submit the average values and store it to database...Give me some ideas...This have to be done by php, JavaScript coding...

Comment: First I'd suggest reading the [Help Center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help) This question is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow. Next, I'd suggest trying something on your own then if you get stuck with a specific problem, come back here and ask about it.

Comment: I have tried but I can't  do that average calculation...we have to exclude the null value...give any example how to calculate average from a column when we have to exclude the null value...any small example you can give..